# What is the best way to store data where one column has values that repeat ranging anywhere from 1-300+ times?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've used web scraping to grab approximately 10,000 movies and all their associated review pages URLs, and the next step for me is to grab every single one of those reviews so that I can get the overall positive/negative reviews using sentiment analysis.

I'm writing all this in Python and am using the Pandas library as my means of pre-processing and structuring all the data. Already I have around 36,000 rows containing the name of the movie in one column and the URLs in the other, with the movie name being repeated over and over again, and with the average reviews per page being 20 I'm looking at roughly 720,000 rows when all things are said and done.

This is for the final project of the college course I'm taking, and throughout my schooling I've come to fear data redundancy in databases. I will eventually be writing all of this to a PostgreSQL database so users can query any movie to get back the prediction, and I'm having a hard time overlooking the fact that these movie titles are being repeated so often.

I was wondering if there was a better way to go about this (which could also hopefully save me some processing time), any help would be greatly appreciated!

I feel like this is more of a direct question than a code issue, but if necessary I can provide any relevant code.

Comment: That `DataFrame` has a unique key `['movie_name', 'URL']` so I don't think you can get around the amount of information you need to store. You *can* convert the movie_names to a categorical variable, which should be better than your object type column. I don't quite understand the organization of your second table, but perhaps consider aggregating review scores before merging them, so the size doesn't grow as much.

Comment: @ALollz thank you for the reply, I'm not familiar with categorical variables but I'll look into it. I didn't explain the second table well enough, the second table will contain new columns for the numerical values of the prediction weighting, as well as another for if it's positive/negative. I've realized as well that the final table I'll be using for the web application will have 1 row for each movie (movie_title, overall_sentiment, most_positive_review, most_negative_review) or something a long those lines. I've still got quite a bit of planning to do! Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

If all the information you have about each movie, there is no redundancy (in the relational sense) , since this is the unique identifier.

You could save some space by having a separate `movie` table that contains an artificial numeric ID and the name and reference the ID from the main table, but that will make your queries more complicated and seems unnecessary for a small table like this.

What I would be more concerned about is whether the movie name is a good identifier at all: what if two movies have the same name? In this age of remakes, that is not a rarity.

Comment: Good points! I guess I got caught up with the amount of rows which made me think the table is larger than it actually is, since there are very few columns. I've only got the two at the moment but I'll probably end up having around six. And you're right, separating the tables would complicate the queries, right now having it in one table makes it a lot easier to export/import into DataFrames. And thanks for bringing up the concern, I made sure to consider that, and luckily for me Rotten Tomatoes will append the movie year onto the end of the title if two have the same name so no dupes. Thanks!